# DKIM clash between Mailgun and MailChimp

Tags: mailchimp, mailgun

I have both a MailChimp and Mandrill account and for obvious reasons, I'm migrating from Mandrill to Mailgun, but keeping MailChimp for now.

MailChimp requires the following DKIM record (CNAME):

```
k1._domainkey.example.com -> dkim.mcsv.net
```

Mailgun requires the following DKIM record (TXT):

```
k1._domainkey.example.com -> k=rsa; p=REDACTED
```

But these DNS records can't coexist because they have the same host name. How can I continue to use both MailChimp (for marketing) and start using Mailgun (for transactional email) on the same domain?

Comment: Unfortunately it wouldn't be ideal for me to take down my Mailgun domain and recreate it, since it's actively used for sending/receiving email. I added a bounty and I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve recreating the domain in Mailgun.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The clashing subdomains was a coincidence. I deleted and recreated the domain in Mailgun and it gave me a totally different TXT record host - `mailo` instead of `k1`. No wonder Google wasn't my friend.

Comment: Experiencing this problem as well. Beware though, deleting the domain in Mailgun will change api keys, passwords, etc. We wished we could use this solution.

Answer (score 11):

Now is possible to change the DKIM Selector from the Domain Settings

[image]

Comment: how? There is no "edit" button on your screenshot (in my Domain Setting neither)

Comment: wow! "edit" button became available after failed 
 DNS records cheking

Comment: Hi there! Could you please clarify this post? Is this setting still available in MailChimp?

Comment: This setting is in Mailgun not Mailchimp, I dont know if Mailchimp allows this change, though all you need is one to be different

Comment: this really helped me in Mailgun! To add to @H1D's response, I had to change the DKIM to fail verification, which allowed me to change the DKIM Selector